# Is there a word for "testing a test"

Tags: single-word-requests

For example testing a test in software.

Validation or proof are near it, but I think it has not directly that meaning.
Validating a test, or proofing a test, they could imply that a test of the test is involved, but not necessarily.

Comment: Next you’ll want to know about testing the test of a test.

Comment: Do you mean something other than validating? Validation means ensuring a test is valid, i.e. it detects what it is supposed to detect. I guess there are other things you might do to your tests, such as measuring the resources they consume and how long they take, checking that they follow good coding practices, checking they match the stated requirements, etc, although maybe these could be called validation too.

Comment: Then there’s the difference between validation (assessment of suitability for purpose) and verification (ensuring correctness of implementation and operation/fulfillment of requirements)

Comment: Please show how this word would be used in sentences.

Comment: @Jim.  Lol, That is actually what I do.  Test testing of tests.

Comment: No. If you're testing a test, then that's what you say. People test tests all the time, for accuracy, for effectiveness, for efficiency, for functionality, for bias, for all sorts of reasons.

Comment: - The tests have passed successfully.  
- The tests of the tests have passed successfully.  

Yeah what Jim wrote, what about more recursion?

The etymology of test is interesting, https://www.etymonline.com/word/test 
> "small vessel used in assaying precious metals," from Old French test, from Latin testum "earthen pot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeap, it is a word "check". You can **check** the test - but **can't test** the test - because **the test** exactly done for determination of performance and quality of something.

And after checking procedure you will have a good test or a bad test - but you can't have untested test or successfully tested test because any works with the test to determine is it good or bad or need to be edited is just test adjustment. You can have the test but it can't be tested because if it does not work - it will not be the test at all, but if it does work - now it is the test and now it can be good or bad or different.

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon where I am in the process I refer to this as "validation of the test cases or of the test plans" or "approval of the test cases or test plans".  "Validation of test cases" is closer to the meaning I want, meaning the test cases designed by testers will accurately evaluate the feature.  I usually refer to "test cases being approved or not" to demonstrate it is the test cases which have been validated because there is the protentional to mix up the validation of the testing of the software with the validation of the software.

This article "https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/validation-testing/" differentiates the validation of testing and testing validation.